# How can I change default font in Windows 10?

Tags: browser, windows-10, fonts

I would like to change the default font in Windows 10 that is used by web browsers or websites. I installed some fonts on my system and now websites that use my system default font, like Yahoo Answers, are showing in bold italic Helvetica Neue. This does not seem to be a browser issue as my font has changed on all my browsers. I want it to change back to whatever the standard default was.

Answer (score 0):

Some incorrectly written fonts will map over other fonts, like Arial.ttf. This has not been a problem until Windows 10 and the changes made with DirectWrite.

FIX:
If you are in Windows 10, there are no fonts older than 1/26/2012 installed by default. Find all fonts older than this date, and delete them while Chrome or any other application with font problems is open. The font causing the problem (taking over Arial.ttf) will not be able to be deleted until Chrome, etc. is closed. Restore the fonts you just deleted except for the font that wouldn't let you delete it. If the problem is still not solved, try again. I was able to fix my pc, and many others using this method, and this method only, other than a clean install with no additional fonts installed afterwards.